# Time Difference is wrongly calculated in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a project using Ruby 2.2 and Rails 4 and sqlite database in which time difference is wrongly calculated.

I have used TimeDifference method for that purpose.

In my database there is a table MachineAttendance.

InTime is stored as  Tue, 12 Feb 2017 20:30:00 UTC +00:00

OutTime is stored as Tue, 12 Feb 2017 05:30:00 UTC +00:00

```
@c1.in_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")

"08:30 PM"

@c1.out_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")

"05:30 AM"

And my method is

time_diff=TimeDifference.between(@c1.in_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'), @c1.out_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')).in_hours.to_f

its giving 15.0 hrs which is wrong

as it should be 9.0 hrs.
```

will anyone let me know how may i get correct difference.....thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below its work for me

```
Time.at((@c1.out_time-@c1.in_time).round.abs).utc.strftime "%H:%M"
```

It will return time like "09:00"

Comment: Will u pls let me know, but problem is its giving result in "8:30" format.Now how may i subtract it from "5:30" so i get difference of "3:00" .

Comment: If your both object is Time object than it will directly give otherwise you need to convert in to it in Time.

Comment: How may i convert  "00:15" into hours.As i need to send this value in hours in database.I have used ("00:15".to_time) / 1.hours,  but its giving error as "NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for 2017-02-16 00:15:00 +0530:Time"

Comment: You can not divide. Its hour will be 00. 
  
      "00:15".to_time.strftime("%H")   It will return hours from time and it will be "00"

Comment: But "00" is not the required output as 15 mins is equivalent to 0.25 hrs but using above i'm getting "00".

Comment: @t = "00:15".to_time
@t.strftime("%H").to_i + @t.strftime("%M").to_f/60

it will return that you want

Comment: How may i convert 0.75 hrs to "0:45" minutes.

Comment: late_working_hrs = (ea1.working_hrs.to_time - lmm.late_mark.to_time) / 1.hours  because in this situation error is coming  *** ArgumentError Exception: argument out of range,as working_hrs is in 0.75 format in database,so difference is not coming,so i need to convert it into "0:45" min.

Comment: Thank you need to convert 0.75 in hours.

Comment: Not in hours,i need to convert it into "0:45" minutes again.

Comment: 0.75 is the value which is gone in database,but i need to convert it into minutes,after performing calculation, need to update in database.

Comment: Time.at(0.75.round.abs).utc.strftime("%H:%M") it will return in 00:45 min

Comment: 2.1.8 :018 > Time.at(0.75.round.abs).utc.strftime("%H:%M") 
 => "00:00"

Comment: its returnig "00:00" not "00:45"

Comment: Time.at(0.75*3600.round.abs).utc.strftime("%H:%M")

Comment: hi, I am fine.
and you?

Comment: do you know the solution of multiple pdf in email question, which i posted recently????   @Divyang

Comment: the solution is very important for me???? please tell na...if u know????